# Refresh page in redirectTo using $routeprovider

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

As shown below, I'm trying to reload the whole page with home directory as target url. But only the control is getting loaded instead of reload.
How can I achieve page reload functionality in 'otherwise' instead of just loading a control?

```
 myApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/Admin/ConfigPanel', {
            templateUrl: '/Admin/ConfigPanel/ManageRoles'
        }).
                otherwise({
               redirectTo: '/Home/Index'
        });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `target="_self"` inside your `<a>` link

```
<a href="/Admin/ConfigPanel/ManageRoles" target="_self">Manage Roles</a>
```